# Visual Studio 2015 - WP8 Application could not be launched for debugging

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015

I've been developing an app for Windows Phone 8 in Visual Studio 2013 without any problems. I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community and I now can't Debug the application.

The application is deployed to the phone but then I get the following error "The application could not be launched for debugging. Ensure that the target device screen is unlocked and that the application is installed."

The device screen is unlocked and the application is successfully installed but then it is not started in order to begin debugging. I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find an solution. This problem never happened neither in VS2012 nor VS2013. I still have VS2013 installed and it successfully debugs the app.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> (Start without debugging works fine but I can't debug.)
And I've already made sure that in Configuration Manager the project is set to deploy.

Also, I've tried cleaning, rebuilding the solution, restarting VS2015, rebooting the pc, rebooting the phone and nothing worked.

[Edited]

If I create a WP8.1 app, the same happens with the new solution/project. If I create a W10 App, the Windows Phone Emulator works but when I try to deploy/run to local machine, it gives an error of "The system cannot find the specified file".

On top of that, when I start VS2015, I get an error and this is what I found in the ActivityLog.xml:

```xml
<record>10408</record>
<time>2015/09/01 13:41:43.306</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
<description>System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Package.Common.14.0.0, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.&#x000D;&#x000A;File name: &apos;Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Package.Common.14.0.0, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliTrace.SourceControl.HistoricalModeHint.HistoricalModeTagger..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ITextBuffer buffer, IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService adapterFactory)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliTrace.SourceControl.HistoricalModeHint.HistoricalModeTaggerProvider.CreateTagger[T](ITextBuffer buffer)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.GatherTaggers(ITextBuffer textBuffer)&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.&#x000D;&#x000A;To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.&#x000D;&#x000A;Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.&#x000D;&#x000A;To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].&#x000D;&#x000A;</description>
```

I tried repairing the VS2015 installation but the problem persists after repair.

Comment: If you create a new solution and deploy it works? I.e. without any of the old code? Have you updated the project to enable it to run in VS 2015?

Comment: @JTIM, I've updated the question as to answer your questions.